# Python running synchronously? Running one executable at a time

Tags: python, executable, os.system

Trying to use python to control numerous compiled executables, but running into timeline issues! I need to be able to run two executables simultaneously, and also be able to 'wait' until an executable has finished prior to starting another one. Also, some of them require superuser. Here is what I have so far:

```
import os
sudoPassword = "PASS"
executable1 = "EXEC1"
executable2 = "EXEC2"
executable3 = "EXEC3"
filename = "~/Desktop/folder/"
commandA = filename+executable1
commandB = filename+executable2
commandC = filename+executable3
os.system('echo %s | sudo %s; %s' % (sudoPassword, commandA, commandB))
os.system('echo %s | sudo %s' % (sudoPassword, commandC))
print ('DONESIES')
```

Assuming that os.system() waits for the executable to finish prior to moving to the next line, this should run EXEC1 and EXEC2 simultaneously, and after they finish run EXEC3...
But it doesn't. Actually, it even prints 'DONESIES' in the shell before commandB even finishes...
Please help!

Comment: You're overriding `os.system`. Call the function instead of assigning to it: `os.system('echo %s | sudo %s' % (sudoPassword, commandC))`

Comment: using

   `from subprocess import call `

not sure I can use as superuser. I've tried running IDLE as sudo, but it doesn't process the commands in
`call()`
as sudo. Could you explain a little further?

Comment: What do you want to happen to the stdout/stderr of the called programs? Display on screen... write to log file?

Comment: Just so you know, `sudo foo; bar` does not run bar with sudo powers. You'd need something like `sudo -c sh "foo; bar"` or call each command independently.

Answer (score 1):

Your script will still execute all 3 commands sequentially. In shell scripts, the semicolon is just a way to put more than one command on one line. It doesn't do anything special, it just runs them one after the other.

If you want to run external programs in parallel from a Python program, use the `subprocess` module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: syntax error, I shouldn't have had the `=` between `os.system` and `('echo...` , that has been updated above.

Comment: My point regarding sequential execution still stands. Read the documentation for `subprocess.Popen`.

Answer (score 1):

Use subprocess.Popen to run multiple commands in the background. If you just want the program's stdout/err to go to the screen (or get dumped completely) its pretty straight forward. If you want to process the output of the commands... that gets more complicated. You'd likely start a thread per command.

But here is the case that matches your example:

```
import os
import subprocess as subp

sudoPassword = "PASS"
executable1 = "EXEC1"
executable2 = "EXEC2"
executable3 = "EXEC3"
filename = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/folder/")
commandA = os.path.join(filename, executable1)
commandB = os.path.join(filename, executable2)
commandC = os.path.join(filename, executable3)

def sudo_cmd(cmd, password):
    p = subp.Popen(['sudo', '-S'] + cmd, stdin=subp.PIPE)
    p.stdin.write(password + '\n')
    p.stdin.close()
    return p

# run A and B in parallel
exec_A = sudo_cmd([commandA], sudoPassword)
exec_B = sudo_cmd([commandB], sudoPassword)

# wait for A before starting C
exec_A.wait()
exec_C = sudo_cmd([commandC], sudoPassword)

# wait for the stragglers
exec_B.wait()
exec_C.wait()

print ('DONESIES')
```